# Error in accessing methods from other class in Spring Java

Tags: java, spring

I am having a Spring controller, which is ProvideDetails.java

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/json/provideDetails")
public class ProvideDetails{
     @RequestMapping(method = {RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST}, value = "/new.json")
     public Builder details(HttpServletRequest request){
          return Provide.method("XYZ");
}
```

This is the Provide.java file,

```
public class Provide{
     public static Builder method(String name){
          Builder builder = Builder.builder()
               .name(name)
               .age(15)
               .build();
          return builder;
     }
}
```

The following is the Builder class, Builder.java which is built by lombok Builder

```
@Builder
@Getter
public class Builder{
     private String name;
     private int age;
}
```

I am not able to make the request mapping to the Controller as it is failing. Where am I going wrong?
The following is the error,

```
[DEBUG] (http-8443-5) org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet: Could not complete request { java.lang.NullPointerException
at sharath.project.web.Provide.method(Provide.java:49)
at sharath.project.web.ProvideDetails.details(ProvideDetails.java:56)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor104.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
```

Comment: what is `Provide.java` line 49?

Comment: The Provide.java class, the second code snippet

Comment: The error says NullPointer, while debugging do you see if the `name` has any data ?

Comment: @TrishulSinghChoudhary, name will akways have some data

Comment: @SharathKamlekar then please point out which is line 49 in Provide.java Something is ofcourse being passed as null somewhere and hence you get the Null Pointer

Comment: @SharathKamlekar I know this is hte class, but the error says line 49, you gave us 9 lines... so which line is 49 in your code? and what do we don't see from it?

Answer (score 0):

If you are in troubles with NullPointer you can try it

```
package sample;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@lombok.Builder
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
class Person{
    private String name;
    private int age;

    public String toString() {
        return "Name: " + name + " Age: " + age;
    }
}

public class AppTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Person person = Person.builder().name("Java").age(50).build();
        System.out.println(person);
    }

}
```

If you replace the "Java" string with any null variable, the NullPointer exception will be displayed. Sometimes, however, Lombok's settings can be challenging. With my EclipseOx, I needed additional configurations to get it work.

Go to the project properties, Java Compiler, Annotation Processing and check the Enable annotation processing option.

[image]